# Show that $\cap _{M>0} \{z: -M<f(z)<M \}$ is connected.

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $f$ is an entire function such that $f(0)=0$ and for every $M>0$, the set $\{z\in \mathbb{C}: -M<f(z)<M\}$ is connected. Show that $\cap_{M>0} \{z\in \mathbb{C}: -M<f(z)<M\}$ is connected.

I know that the intersection of nested, connected, compact sets is connected, but we do not have compactness here. A hint would be most welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe it is $-M < |f(z)|<M$?

Comment: However, this intersection must be $f^{-1}(0)$, which is a discrete set... So being connected means being the only point $\{  0 \}$, or the whole $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean. The answers have assumed that you mean $|f(z)| < M$. Another possible interpretation is to look at the points $z$ where $f(z)$ is *real* and between $-M$ and $M$. Which one do you mean? (It would be silly to use $-M$ if the modulus is intended, so I'm guessing it's the second one.)

Comment: Upon my first reading of the question, I thought it should be $|f(z)|<M$ instead of $-M<f(z)<M$. But the writer of the exam assured me it is not a typo.

Comment: The original problem is to show $f(z)=cz^n$ under the hypotheses above. Showing that the zero set is connected will show that $0$ is the only zero of $f$, and then all that needs to be shown is that $f$ is a polynomial. The only difficulty I have with this argument is showing $\cap_{M>0} \{z:-M<f(z)<M\}$ is connected. Does this help?

Comment: If $f$ is complex valued, then $<$  makes no sense. In any case, the $|f(z)| < M$ used in the answers below is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $f$ is not identically zero. Then the intersection (i.e. $f^{-1}(0)$) is discrete.
Then for sufficiently small $r>0$, $f$ has no zero on $r\cdot S^1$. Let $h_r>0$ be the minimum of the continuous function $|f(z)|$ on this compact set. We conclude that the single connected component of $\{\,z\in\mathbb C:|f|<h_r\,\}$ is fully inside $rS 1$, i.e in $r\mathbb D$. Then 
$$\bigcap_{M>0}\{\,z\in\mathbb C:|f|<M\,\} \subseteq \bigcap _{r>0}r\mathbb D=\{0\}.$$

Answer (score -2):

If $f$ is constant, then we must have $f=0$ and the result follows, so assume $f$ is not constant.

Let $L_M = \{ z | |f(z)| < M \}$. Then $z \in L_M$ for all $M>0$ **iff** $|f(z)| <M$ for all $M>0$ **iff** $f(z) = 0$.

Let $L^* = \cap_{M>0} L_M = f^{-1}( \{0\})$.
We are given that $f(0) = 0$, hence $0 \in L^*$

Suppose there is another zero $z \neq 0$. Since $L_M$ is open and connected, it is path connected, hence for $M={1 \over n}$ there is a path $\gamma_n$ from $0$ to $z$.

Pick any $\delta>0$ such that $\delta < |z|$, and let $z_n$ be a point on $\gamma_n$ such that $|z_n| = \delta$. The sequence $z_n$ has an accumulation point $z_\delta$ and we must have $f(z_\delta) = 0$. Since $\delta>0$ was arbitrary, it follows that $f=0$, a contradiction.

Hence we see that $L^* = \{0\}$.

Comment: a) $\bigcap_{M>0}L_M=f^{-1}(0)$ and then b) this does not address connectedness

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: First, the OP asked for a hint. Second, my initial answer was certainly a little terse, but it did point out that the intersection was either the entire plane or the origin, which addresses a) and (weakly) b).

Comment: Why the downvotes?